# JQuery Mobile pageinit for Two Pages

Tags: jquery-mobile

I already below for JQM page with id `page1`:

```
$('#page1').live('pageinit', function(event, data){

});
```

If I have another JQM page with id `page2` and want to have the same `pageinit` with `page1`, how to call it or add the event without copying all the code at `page1 pageinit` event.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`$('#page1,#page2')` should do the trick.

Pls refer - http://api.jquery.com/multiple-selector/

Answer (score 0):

I think it will be triggered only once in a multi-page template.

See page load events and page change events:
http://jquerymobile.com/test/docs/api/events.html